# Java JDBC Access denied for user

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying make a connection to MySQL from my java application and it keeps on saying :

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'vincent'@'x.x.x.x'
>   (using password: YES)

I have checked in phpmyadmin that vincent can conect from any host and I also have a python script who can connect with the same username/password without any problem

What is the problem ?

Thank you very much

Regards.

Comment: Can you connect to x.x.x.x using the `mysql` command line tool from the host that you're trying to run your Java application from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try granting all privileges to your user from any machine in mysql:

```
 grant all on db_name.* to ‘vincent’@'%';
```

where db_name is your database name ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd GRANT permissions:

```
create database foobar;
create user foobar identified by 'foobar';
grant all on foobar.* to 'foobar'@'%' identified by 'foobar';
grant all on foobar.* to 'foobar'@'localhost' identified by 'foobar';
```

You need the user's host machine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_base.* TO db_user @'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_passwd';
```

You have to give access to user on db. and yes if you are being using a user defined stored procedure and function then also use

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO 'db_user'@'%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `userid` and `password` while getting connection object:

```
Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection("protocol","userid","password");
```