# how to store data using others ip(which is connected in lan) into mysqldb

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.0.108'
> (using password: YES)     at
> com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
> ```

**This is connection url of other**:

```
mysql_connection_string=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.101:3306/
```

Comment: Show what you've already tried

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: MySQL server needs to be given permission to allow connection from `root` user at `192.168.0.108`. Check https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

You will need to have access to your MySQL server, in order to be able to give permission.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java JDBC Access denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224898/java-jdbc-access-denied-for-user)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to ever use the root user from any kind of application. Too much privileges which can cause a lot of trouble if your app ever gets compromised.

That said, by default the root user in MySQL doesn't allow connections from anywhere other than localhost, which explains the `access denied` error.

It's best if you create a new user, with all the privileges it'll normally use on all tables (SELECT, CREATE, UPDATE, etc on *.*) and allow connections for that user from any host (`'username'@'%'`)