# Hibernate is able to connect to mysql but Spring JPA does not

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am developing a basic application that already works with  hibernate and  wanted to add spring JPA capabilities to make it more simpler.

When I test  with hibernate, I am able to connect to the mysql database without  any issues. But when I test the application from spring boot, the database access fails. I have given the same credentials in both hibernate.cfg.xml and application.properties. But not sure why the spring access is failing.

I tried granting the privileges to the user. But still not working.

```
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'logesh'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/devops</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">logesh</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">logesh</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

application.properties

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/devops
    spring.datasource.username=logesh
    spring.datasource.password=logesh   
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```

Following is the error I am getting for spring boot:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'logesh'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
```

Following is the MySQL general log where we can see that the spring boot login  fails. Subsequently when trying with the hibernate it is able to login.

```
    2018-12-09T12:48:52.494621Z   150 Connect   logesh@localhost on devops using SSL/TLS
    2018-12-09T12:48:52.494773Z   150 Connect   Access denied for user 'logesh'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    2018-12-09T12:48:54.243711Z   151 Connect   logesh@localhost on devops using SSL/TLS
    2018-12-09T12:48:54.243881Z   151 Connect   Access denied for user 'logesh'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    2018-12-09T12:48:56.328126Z   152 Connect   logesh@localhost on devops using SSL/TLS
    2018-12-09T12:48:56.328291Z   152 Connect   Access denied for user 'logesh'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    2018-12-09T13:10:46.485311Z   153 Connect   root@localhost on devops using SSL/TLS
    2018-12-09T13:10:46.486314Z   153 Query select @@version_comment limit 1
    2018-12-09T13:11:07.220308Z   153 Quit  
    2018-12-09T13:12:52.763898Z   154 Connect   logesh@localhost on devops using SSL/TLS
    2018-12-09T13:12:52.764643Z   154 Query select @@version_comment limit 1
    2018-12-09T13:13:15.186763Z   154 Quit  
    2018-12-09T13:27:57.857455Z   155 Connect   logesh@localhost on devops using SSL/TLS
    2018-12-09T13:27:57.861872Z   155 Query /* mysql-connector-java-8.0.13 (Revision: 66459e9d39c8fd09767992bc592acd2053279be6) */SELECT  @@session.auto_increment_increment AS auto_increment_increment, @@character_set_client AS character_set_client, @@character_set_connection AS character_set_connection, @@character_set_results AS character_set_results, @@character_set_server AS character_set_server, @@collation_server AS collation_server, @@collation_connection AS collation_connection, @@init_connect AS init_connect, @@interactive_timeout AS interactive_timeout, @@license AS license, @@lower_case_table_names AS lower_case_table_names, @@max_allowed_packet AS max_allowed_packet, @@net_write_timeout AS net_write_timeout, @@sql_mode AS sql_mode, @@system_time_zone AS system_time_zone, @@time_zone AS time_zone, @@transaction_isolation AS transaction_isolation, @@wait_timeout AS wait_timeout
    2018-12-09T13:27:57.877332Z   155 Query SET NAMES utf8mb4
```

I am stuck here and any help would be appreciated.

Reply to Comment:

```
    mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'logesh'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%logesh%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. TO 'logesh'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%logesh%' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1
    mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'logesh'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%logesh%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY '%logesh%' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1
    mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'logesh'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

I could execute only the third command, which I already tried.

**Edit:** 
This question is not a duplicate of [Java JDBC Access denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224898/java-jdbc-access-denied-for-user), as I have tried all solutions recommended there before posting this question.

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'logesh'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%logesh%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: @INDRESHKHANDELWAL : I tried the  commands already, but didn't work... i will post that result too...

Comment: Can you please check if there is any space after your username or password in the property file. If there is any space after `logesh`, just remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There were trailing spaces. I corrected it and it works now :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java JDBC Access denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224898/java-jdbc-access-denied-for-user)

Comment: @AbhishekPatyal ca you please post your solution as an answer, I shall accept that and close this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there are some trailing spaces after the username.
Can you please check if there is any space after your username or password in the property file. If there is any space after `logesh`, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Spring Boot and MySQL are you using? I created a minimal app and it is working just fine (source code here: https://github.com/behrangsa/stackoverflow-q53692999).

Also notice that the current JDBC driver class name for MySQL is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.

### Run MySQL

```
↪ docker run -P --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=logesh -d mysql:8                                                                                                   00:52:54
cc395e45faa5d1cc3fdff3eeb35a6491202b75862ae5a519901c10fe02a80403
↪ docker ps                                                                                                                                                                  00:53:08
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                               NAMES
cc395e45faa5        mysql:8             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:32773->3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32772->33060/tcp   some-mysql
```

### Create database and user

```
CREATE DATABASE devops;
CREATE USER 'logesh' IDENTIFIED BY 'logesh';
GRANT ALL ON devops.* TO 'logesh';
```

### `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>q53692999</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>q53692999</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### Configure properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:32773/devops
spring.datasource.username=logesh
spring.datasource.password=logesh
```

### Run app:

```
     .   ____          _            __ _ _
    /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
   ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
    \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
     '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
    =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
    :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.1.RELEASE)

   2018-12-17 00:51:56.267  INFO 16686 --- [           main] com.stackoverflow.q53692999.Main         : Starting Main on apadana with PID 16686 (~/Documents/projects/q53692999/target/classes started by foo in ~/Documents/projects/q53692999)
   2018-12-17 00:51:56.269  INFO 16686 --- [           main] com.stackoverflow.q53692999.Main         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
   2018-12-17 00:51:56.553  INFO 16686 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
   2018-12-17 00:51:56.568  INFO 16686 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 11ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
   2018-12-17 00:51:56.777  INFO 16686 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
   2018-12-17 00:51:56.965  INFO 16686 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
   2018-12-17 00:51:56.994  INFO 16686 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
   2018-12-17 00:51:57.022  INFO 16686 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
   2018-12-17 00:51:57.023  INFO 16686 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
   2018-12-17 00:51:57.084  INFO 16686 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
   2018-12-17 00:51:57.142  INFO 16686 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
   2018-12-17 00:51:57.444  INFO 16686 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
   2018-12-17 00:51:57.526  INFO 16686 --- [           main] com.stackoverflow.q53692999.Main         : Started Main in 1.446 seconds (JVM running for 1.746)
   2018-12-17 00:51:57.529  INFO 16686 --- [       Thread-5] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
   2018-12-17 00:51:57.531  INFO 16686 --- [       Thread-5] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
   2018-12-17 00:51:57.534  INFO 16686 --- [       Thread-5] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

   Process finished with exit code 0
```